# Expectation using a dirac measure as the probability measure

Tags: measure-theory, expectation

If $\varepsilon_a(dx)$ is the point mass at point $a\in\mathbb{R}$, I want to calculate $E_a[X]$ where $X$ is a real valued random variable and $E_a$ is expectation with respect to $\varepsilon_a(dx)$.

I'm not sure if my understanding is correct:

$$E_a[X]=\int_{\Omega} X\cdot\varepsilon_a(dx)=\int X1_{\{a\}}(x)dx=a$$

i.e. only when X takes the value of $a$ does the integrand be anything other than 0. Since $a$ is a point on real line, there is only one such point?

Comment: This makes sense only when $\Omega=\mathbb R$ (and then the result would be $X(a)$, not $a$). Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Yes I think $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ here. How did you get the result $X(a)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega=\mathbb R$ (otherwise the question makes no sense). For every $a$ in $\Omega$ and every random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R^n$, by definition of the [Dirac measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure) $\delta_a$,
$$
\int_\Omega X\,\mathrm d\delta_a=\int_\Omega X(\omega)\,\mathrm d\delta_a(\omega)=X(a).
$$